# Getting object from memcached and setting to self in PHP

Tags: php, memcached

I have a user class mapped to a database row. I am caching it in memcached as key value pair with userid as memcached key. I want to encapsulate all user functionality into user class including populating user class fields. While fetching from PDO, I use PDO::FETCH_INTO to store values in self object. How to do it with memcached ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, where did you get stuck?

Comment: the problem was to assign values in self object from an object returned by memcached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasing of your question and follow up comments are somewhat ambiguous but still they point me in the following direction:

```
public function __construct($id) {
    global $pdo, $memcached;

    $data = $memcached->get($id);
    if($memcached->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_SUCCESS) {
        // this is not currently allowed in PHP
        $this = $data;

        // this should be your fix
        foreach($data AS $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }

        // or this
        foreach($this AS $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $data[$key];
        }

        // the difference between the fixes above is that
        // the second is strictly limited to values defined
        // by the class (current object)
    }
    else {
        $pdos = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?');
        if($pdos) {
            // this is not allowed in PHP
            $pdos->execute(array(intval($id)));
            $this = $pdos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class($this));

            // all of this should work fine and is allowed
            $pdos->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
            $pdos->execute(array(intval($id)));
            $pdos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO);
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately PHP does not allow overriding  the value of $this internally (inside its own method call) hence what could do as an alternative is to use static methods.

```
public static function getByID($id) {
    global $pdo, $memcached;

    $data = $memcached->get($id);
    if($memcached->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_SUCCESS) {
        // this will work if your objects construct has a 
        // foreach similar to the ones presented above
        $result = new self($data);

        // or if you don't want to write a foreach in
        // the construct you can have it here
        foreach($data AS $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }

        // or here
        foreach($this AS $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $data[$key];
        }
    }
    else {
        $pdos = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?');
        if($pdos) {
            // either of these should work
            $pdos->execute(array(intval($id)));
            $result = $pdos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class($this));

            // either of these should work
            $result = new self;
            $pdos->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $result);
            $pdos->execute(array(intval($id)));
            $pdos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO);
        }
    }

    return($result);
}
```

The usage syntax would be `MyClass::get($some_id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We just implemented something similar to this yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is either "just do it" or " you don't".

if you have your information saved separately as key/values, you can't just do it with one hit, you would just have to retreive them manually (make a new object that fills itself with calculated keys from memcached).

If you have an object serialized in the memcached, you can just retrieve it and unserialize.

Comment: the problem was to assign values in self object from an object returned by memcached.